# How can I manage onClick function from my custom listview adapter in main activity class

Tags: java, android

I've created a custom adapter for a class that have a button . In this code I used onClick function in adapter class but I don't want this . I want to call it from main activity class (Like listview.setOnItemClickListener). How can I do that ? 
Notice that I want be able to get position of button or contact properties

```
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

    Contact contact = contacts.get(position);
    final ViewHolder holder ;
    if (convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) ;
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource,parent,false);
        holder.btnCall = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
        holder.imgAvatar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
        holder.txtName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.txtPhoneNumber = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNumber);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtPhoneNumber.setText(contact.getContactNumber());
    holder.txtName.setText(contact.getContactName());
    int imageId = contact.getGender() == 0 ? R.drawable.male : R.drawable.female;
    holder.imgAvatar.setImageResource(imageId);
    holder.btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, holder.txtName.getText().toString() + " "
                    + holder.txtPhoneNumber.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return convertView ;

}

private class ViewHolder{

    public ImageView imgAvatar ;
    public TextView txtPhoneNumber ;
    public TextView txtName ;
    public Button btnCall ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an interface with methods that with params of data that you want to pass and then pass the interface to the adapter and implement that interface in the activity

Answer (score 1):

You can set onItemClickListener in main class after setting the adapter like the example given below:

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                int position, long id) {
        final String item =(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        list.remove(item);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Tnx but I want to call a function when user clicked on special button in list view rather than list view items . Suppose I have two or more buttons in a single list view item and each of them has it's own function

Answer (score 0):

Add the onClickListener to your Button in getView() of your ListAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Remove on click listener from adapter and set listview on click listener. Get data from contact array from on click position.